# Python saving large simulation

Tags: python, matlab

I am coming from Matlab background and recently started coding in Python. I generate massive data using Monte Carlo and these are sometimes 10 dimensional arrays. In Matlab I have been using .mat file format to store these arrays, along with inputs and other parameters using struct.

What is the recommended storage or equivalent for Python ?

Comment: coming from a MATLAB guy, you can still save/load MAT-files in Python using SciPy: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.io.savemat.html :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard object serialization in python is [pickle](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html). From the docs

> “Pickling” is the process whereby a Python object hierarchy is
>   converted into a byte stream, and “unpickling” is the inverse
>   operation, whereby a byte stream (from a binary file or bytes-like
>   object) is converted back into an object hierarchy.

An example would be

```
import pickle
mydata = [1, 2, 3, 5]
pickle.dump(mydata, open("mydata.p", "wb"))
mydata2 = pickle.load(open("mydata.p", "rb"))
```

An alternative would be to use something like [h5py](http://www.h5py.org/) which is a third party module for writing data to HDF5 format. Depending on your application, this could be a more performant solution since HDF5 is designed with large numerical data sets in mind. In fact, the latest .mat files are actual designed on top of hdf5 files, [source](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/import_export/mat-file-versions.html).

Answer (score 1):

you can use serialization objects in python with pickle library or cplicke for (python 2.x),

https://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html
example:
if you want save as file

```
 import pickle
 filetocreate = open('newfile.txt','w')
 pickle.dump(arrayxD, filetocreate, -1 )
```

then use you can use

```
 pickle.load(file)
```

-# Pickle the list using the highest protocol available. = -1
-# if not = 0

See:
pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL

```
An integer, the highest protocol version available. This value can be passed as a protocol value to functions dump() and dumps() as well as the Pickler constructor.
```

pickle.DEFAULT_PROTOCOL

```
An integer, the default protocol version used for pickling. May be less than HIGHEST_PROTOCOL. Currently the default protocol is 3, a new protocol designed for Python 3.
```